# How to end window function SQL after a certain row with condition in a title

Tags: sql, window-functions

everyone!

I have a table, before it I appended rang for each purchase. Like this:

| id | date | time | title | rang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:00 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:10 | B | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:20 | BUY C | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:20 | D | 4 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:30 | E | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:40 | BUY F | 6 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:50 | G | 7 |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:00 | A_1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:20 | BUY B_1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:20 | C_1 | 3 |

But I would end window function after a certain row, which has "BUY in title.
I tried to use:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time ASC RESET WHEN title LIKE '%BUY%')
```

But it doesn't work. The result is as followed:

| id | date | time | title | rang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:00 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:10 | B | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:20 | BUY C | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:00 | A_1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:20 | BUY B_1 | 2 |

All end on the row with word BUY on a first time

Comment: Could you please tag the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: If an id has no BUY row, is it still expected to show up in the result? See difference at https://dbfiddle.uk/MK1gLMX0

Comment: @SelVazi What is RDBMS? I don't know what it is. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the running total provided by the window function `SUM()` to identify the initial occurrence of a row containing "BUY" in its title. Subsequently, we can join this dataset with your table based on the condition that the 'rang' value should be lower than that of the first row featuring 'BUY'.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%BUY%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) AS sm
  FROM mytable
) AS s ON s.id = t.id AND t.rang <= s.rang
WHERE s.sm = 1 AND s.title LIKE '%BUY%';
```

Results :

```
id  date        time                title   rang
1   2023-03-03  2023-03-03 10:00:00 A       1
1   2023-03-03  2023-03-03 10:10:00 B       2
1   2023-03-03  2023-03-03 10:20:00 BUY C   3
2   2023-03-03  2023-03-03 12:00:00 A_1     1
2   2023-03-03  2023-03-03 12:20:00 BUY B_1 2
```

[Demo on mysql 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/ApWBtivh)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've done it and everything is great! @SelVazi